# Autolayout not working only in iPhone 7 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

autolayout is not working only in iPhone 7 plus

it can't be center both horizontal and vertical

it looks like this

[image]

there is some space, it's not fit! but, it work well in other iphone device

here is iphone 7 ( there is no empty space compare to iphone 7 plus )

[image]

I can see that image alignment is x,y center in indicator

here is constraint

[image]

image size is

@1x:320x100 / @2x:640x200 / @3x:960x300

I think image size is correct...

Comment: Shouldn't your image size @3x be 960x300?  Can you share more of your layout and what 'is working' looks like and 'not working' looks like?

Comment: @dmorrow oh, sorry! 3x size is 960x300! okay

Answer (score 0):

What is your `imageView.contentMode`?  It seems like it is not scaling up the image.  An iPhone 7s width is `414pt`.  `414pt - 28pt * 2 = 358pt`.  Your image would have to be at least `358pt` wide to not have any padding and not require upscaling.  That would be `1074x336` for the @3x dimensions.

Alternatively, just set the contentMode to `.scaleAspectFill`.  Rather than having the rounded corners in the image itself, you could set the imageView to have rounded corners, to make scaling easier.